# Can someone provide a translation of this old HK smoking ad?

Tags: translation, characters, cantonese, traditional-characters, writing

I came across this interesting smoking ad from Hong Kong, but while I understand a good number of the characters, its hard for me to piece together everything that is being said here:

[image]

From what I can see, it is written from right to left, the top part saying that it is a "golden brand" that smells good. The black box looks like it says its been preserved for three years and I'm guessing its from America (cant make out the part next to it but it looks like "sth...美國." The rest I'm mixed on understanding what it says.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, the character in the ad is 老夫子(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Master_Q), created by Hong Kong manhua artist Alfonso Wong.

Comment: Thats awesome. Thanks for the trivia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long gone are the days when companies would advertise cigarettes

[image]

You can see the brand is "World" on the package, 金牌 (Gold medal) is a Chinese name created by the Hong Kong seller

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you for the translation. Part of the allure of this ad for me is its archaic style haha

Answer (score 4):

the text, and it’s interpretation is:

> 點解金牌濾咀香煙咁好味

why do the golden brand filter cigarettes taste so good

> 因為係選用經過

because it’s selected [from] processing

> 三年蘊藏嘅美國

3 years “storing” (i guess there should be a specialised term in tobacco industry) of american

> “維珍尼亞”

virginia (a us state)

> 煙葉製成

tobacco leaf [for] fabrication

> 順喉・夠味

smooth throat, adequate flavour

> 美國金牌濾咀香煙

the american golden brand filter cigarettes

> 吸一支美國金牌香煙

inhale one, american golden brand cigarette

“吸” in “吸煙”, smoking cigarette is, vernacular chinese; in colloquial cantonese, we use “**食**煙” for cigarette smoking

> 條氣順晒・乜都攪掂

feeling clam / better, everything’s all right

these two cantonese verses might be interpreted differently, depend son the context

have fun :)